# Unity: void OnTriggerEnter2D works first time but then it doesn't work

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I'm trying to detect collision multiple times but it only detects the first time, then it detects nothing. Even when I print, it will only print the first one but then it print nothing.

Code:

```c#
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
{    
    if (col.CompareTag("Wall"))
    {
        print("Wall");
    }
    else if (col.CompareTag("Player"))
    {
        print("Player");
    }
    else if (col.CompareTag("Fly"))
    {
        print("Fly");  
    }   
}
```

Comment: add your code ..

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you need OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D col)